# Laravel array validation for unique attribute in array but not required to be unique in table

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an array in php. i need to validate array such that each abc_id should be unique in array but not required to be unique in database table.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
 'tests.*.*.abc_id' => 'should not be same in array' 
 ]);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel version 5.6

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-distinct) rule of laravel `array` validation.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
          ['products' => 
            ['product_id' => 1, 'quantity' => 5],
            ['product_id' => 1, 'quantity' => 99],
            ['product_id' => 2, 'quantity' => 1],
          ],
          ['products.*.product_id' => 'distinct']
        );
        
        dd($validator->passes());
```