# Laravel validate if same item is selected more than once

Tags: laravel, validation, customization

In my application I have `add more` functionality for selected multiple `devices`. I need to show an error message if the `user` has selected the same `device` two or more times.

Here is my code.

```php
class ValidateDeviceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    private $data = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = request()->all();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'devices' => ['required', 'array'],
            'devices.*.device_company_id' => [
                'required', 
                'integer', 
                'exists:device_companies,id,company_id,' . session()->get('COMPANY_ID')
            ],
        ];

        foreach($this->data['devices'] as $key => $array)
        {
            $rules["devices.{$key}.device_id"] = [
                'required',
                'integer',
                "exists:devices,id,device_company_id," . @$array["device_company_id"]
            ];
        }

        # returning
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to confirm, you are check duplicate devices from your database or from your current request?

Comment: From the current request, not from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just checking duplicated values inside the array. You can use the validation rule [distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-distinct) for this.

```
'devices.*.device_company_id' => [
    'distinct',
    // ...
]
```

If you wish to validate duplicates within a model you can use the rule `unique:model`

Comment: It worked. However, I need to check if the `device_id` not `device_company_id` (which is in the loop) is distinct or not. Also, I found that the `distinct` rule must also be defined in the loop for this to work. I'll post my final code also.

Comment: Should've responded earlier, but weekend and everything. Good work anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tommie. Here is my final code.

```php
class ValidateDeviceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    private $data = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = request()->all();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'devices' => ['required', 'array'],
            'devices.*.device_company_id' => [
                'required', 
                'integer', 
                'exists:device_companies,id,company_id,' . session()->get('COMPANY_ID')
            ],
            'devices.*.device_company_id' => [
                'required',
                'distinct',
            ]
        ];

        foreach($this->data['devices'] as $key => $array)
        {
            $rules["devices.{$key}.device_id"] = [
                'required',
                'distinct',
                'integer',
                "exists:devices,id,device_company_id," . @$array["device_company_id"]
            ];
        }

        # returning
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

I also found this [Laravel array validation for unique attribute in array but not required to be unique in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312972/laravel-array-validation-for-unique-attribute-in-array-but-not-required-to-be-un)