# Laravel Validation Unique Array request

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending a request to my laravel project like below:

```js
{
    "group_name": "Demo",
    "desc": "demo",
    "option_type_id": ["7", "8"],
    "products": [{
            "product_id": 3,
            "product_option_id": ["10", "17"]
        },
        {
            "product_id": 4,
            "product_option_id": ["10", "17"]
        },
        /// more
    ]
}
```

I want To validate that each `product_option_id` array set must be unique.
Like in the above case, it needs to return an array.

```js
{
    "group_name":"Demo",
    "desc":"demo",
    "option_type_id":["7","8"],
    "products":[{
            "product_id":3,
            "product_option_id": ["10","17"]
        },
        {
            "product_id":4,
            "product_option_id": ["10","17"] // error: duplicate entry
        }
    ]
}
```

An example of accepted data:

```js
{
    "group_name": "Demo",
    "desc": "demo",
    "option_type_id": ["7", "8"],
    "products": [{
            "product_id": 3,
            "product_option_id": ["10", "17"]
        },
        {
            "product_id": 4,
            "product_option_id": ["10", "16"] // accepted 
        },
        {
            "product_id": 5,
            "product_option_id": ["10", "18"] // accepted 
        },
        {
            "product_id": 6,
            "product_option_id": ["1", "18"] // accepted 
        }

    ]
}
```

How can I validate this request in my laravel?
I am a beginner, so can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312972/laravel-array-validation-for-unique-attribute-in-array-but-not-required-to-be-un

Comment: @on3ss No i Just Want check with each array like .. the combination should not be repeated values can be reapeated